# SQl Server Password Change after installation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssms, password

I have installed SQL Server 2005, but at the time of installation I forgot to change my password. Now I can access my database only in Windows authentication mode, and I want to access the database in mix mode.  For that I need to know the username and password. Please tell me how I can change the password after installing SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enterprise Manager - Object Explorer - Server - Properties - Security - Server Authentification - Sql Server and Windows Authentification mode.

To change password:  Security - Logins - sa - Password

Don't forget to restart te service

Answer (score 2):

I'll clarify demas's answer:

1. Open SQL Server Management Studio
2. Connect to the SQL Server instance using windows authentication
3. In Object Explorer select the SQL Server and right click it
4. Open Properties
5. Open the Security tab
6. In Server Authentication select Sql Server and Windows Authentification mode

Answer (score 0):

```
1.Login to sql server with windows authentication
2.Right click on server name
3.Click on properties
4.then click on securities
5.Then in Server authentication select mixed mode(windows+sql server authentication)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
USE [master]
GO
ALTER LOGIN [sa] WITH PASSWORD=N'YourNewPassword'
GO
```